# XML Serialization: System.InvalidOperationException: <tagname> was not expected

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, serialization

I'm trying to de-serialize an XML Document and when the desserializer encounters a certain tag about halfway down the doc, it gives the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException <mytagname> was not expected.
```

It has a   `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("MyTagName", typeof(MediaFile))]` tag right before it in the class, and the error is only happening on this one particular tag/class, but I can't find anything different about it that would make this occur. Anyone ever seen this before?

**EDITED FOR MORE DETAIL:**

Here's the deserializer code:

```
 String xmlString = _doc.ToString();
 StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlString);            
 XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr);
 xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(VideoAdServingTemplate<AdNode>));
 objVast = (VideoAdServingTemplate<AdNode>)xs.Deserialize(sr);
```

And the XML in question looks like this:

```
<VideoAdServingTemplate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vast.xsd">
    <Ad id="myad">
        <InLine>
            <AdSystem>MyAdSystem</AdSystem>
            <AdTitle>Advertisement</AdTitle>
            <Description>Shamwow</Description>
            <Survey>
                <URL><![CDATA[http://www.dynamiclogic.com/tracker?campaignId=234&site=yahoo]]></URL>
            </Survey>
            <Error>
                <URL><![CDATA[http://www.primarysite.com/tracker?noPlay=true&impressionTracked=false]]></URL>
            </Error>
            <Impression>
                <URL id="myadsever"><![CDATA[http://www.primarysite.com/tracker?imp]]></URL>
                <URL id="anotheradsever"><![CDATA[http://www.thirdparty.com/tracker?imp]]></URL>
            </Impression>
            <TrackingEvents>
                <Tracking event="start">
                    <URL id="myadsever"><![CDATA[http://www.primarysite.com/tracker?start]]></URL>
                </Tracking>
                <Tracking event="midpoint">
                    <URL id="myadsever"><![CDATA[http://www.primarysite.com/tracker?mid]]></URL>
                    <URL id="anotheradsever"><![CDATA[http://www.thirdparty.com/tracker?mid]]></URL>
                </Tracking>
                <Tracking event="firstQuartile">
                    <URL id="myadsever"><![CDATA[http://www.primarysite.com/tracker?fqtl]]></URL>
                    <URL id="anotheradsever"><![CDATA[http://www.thirdparty.com/tracker?fqtl]]></URL>
                </Tracking>
                <Tracking event="thirdQuartile">
                    <URL id="myadsever"><![CDATA[http://www.primarysite.com/tracker?tqtl]]></URL>
                    <URL id="anotheradsever"><![CDATA[http://www.thirdparty.com/tracker?tqtl]]></URL>
                </Tracking>
                <Tracking event="complete">
                    <URL id="myadsever"><![CDATA[http://www.primarysite.com/tracker?comp]]></URL>
                    <URL id="anotheradsever"><![CDATA[http://www.thirdparty.com/tracker?comp]]></URL>
                </Tracking>
                <Tracking event="mute">
                    <URL id="myadsever"><![CDATA[http://www.primarysite.com/tracker?mute]]></URL>
                </Tracking>
                <Tracking event="pause">
                    <URL id="myadsever"><![CDATA[http://www.primarysite.com/tracker?pause]]></URL>
                </Tracking>
                <Tracking event="replay">
                    <URL id="myadsever"><![CDATA[http://www.primarysite.com/tracker?replay]]></URL>
                </Tracking>
                <Tracking event="fullscreen">
                    <URL id="myadsever"><![CDATA[http://www.primarysite.com/tracker?full]]></URL>
                </Tracking>
                <Tracking event="stop">
                    <URL id="myadsever"><![CDATA[http://www.primarysite.com/tracker?stop]]></URL>
                </Tracking>
            </TrackingEvents>
            <Video>
                <Duration>00:00:15</Duration>
                <AdID>AdID</AdID>
                <VideoClicks>
                    <ClickThrough>
                        <URL id="myadsever"><![CDATA[http://www.primarysite.com/tracker?click]]></URL>
                    </ClickThrough>
                    <ClickTracking>
                        <URL id="anotheradsever"><![CDATA[http://www.thirdparty.com/tracker?click]]></URL>
                        <URL id="athirdadsever"><![CDATA[http://www.thirdparty.com/tracker?click]]></URL>
                    </ClickTracking>
                    <CustomClick>
                        <URL id="redclick"><![CDATA[http://www.thirdparty.com/tracker?click]]></URL>
                        <URL id="blueclick"><![CDATA[http://www.thirdparty.com/tracker?click]]></URL>
                    </CustomClick>
                </VideoClicks>
                <MediaFiles>
                    <MediaFile delivery="streaming" bitrate="250" width="200" height="200" type="video/x-flv">
                        <URL><![CDATA[rtmp://streamingserver/streamingpath/medium/filename.flv]]></URL>
                    </MediaFile>
<MediaFile delivery="progressive" bitrate="400" width="200" height="200" type="video/x-flv">
                        <URL><![CDATA[http://progressive.hostlocation.com//high/filename.flv]]></URL>
                    </MediaFile>
                    <MediaFile delivery="progressive" bitrate="200" width="200" height="200" type="video/x-flv">
                        <URL><![CDATA[http://progressive.hostlocation.com/progressivepath/medium/filename.flv]]></URL>
                    </MediaFile>
<!-- and a few more MediaFile tags -->
</MediaFiles>
</Video>
```

There's a bit more to the XML but its pretty big so I cut a lot out of it. I'm not sure of the order in which everything is deserialized, all I know is the first error I see after calling xs.Deserialize() is:

```
Unhandled Error in Silverlight 2 Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError       
Message: System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 7). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <MediaFile xmlns=''> was not expected.
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderVideoAdServingTemplate1.Read27_VideoAdServingTemplate()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, Object events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
```

There's no indication of what was expected or why this wasn't expected.

The class that implements it has this definition to associate the tag with an object:

```
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("MediaFile", typeof(MediaFile))]
    public MediaFile[] MediaFiles
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mediaFilesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mediaFilesField = value;
        }
    }
```

I assume that the [] in the definition and the use of XmlArrayItemAttribute is because there are multiple MediaFile tags in a row, so they are being placed into an array. I generated this code with xsd.exe and modified it slightly to work in Silverlight.

Comment: Are you serializing or deserializing the XML?  Can you provide a chunk of the XML and the code in question?

Comment: oops, yeah, sorry I wrote this in a hurry. I added more detail and more code.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to pass the MediaFile type in as a KnownType to the serializer:

```
var knownTypes = new Type[] { typeof(MediaFile) };
xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(VideoAdServingTemplate<AdNode>), knownTypes);
```

Otherwise the serializer doesn't know about this new type.

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure that the XML is valid against the same schema that was used to generate your classes. If you still have a problem, please post all three sets of files: the XSD, the XML and the .cs file.